# Trying to delete todo list but not working

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var inputItem = document.getElementById("inputItem");

function addItem(list, input) {

  var inputItem = this.inputItem;
  var list = document.getElementById(list);
  var listItem = document.createElement("li");
  var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.innerText = "delete";

  deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function() {

    //console.log("Delete");
    //var ul=document.getElementById("list");

    var listItem = list.children;
    for (var i=0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
        while(listItem[i] && listItem[i].children[0].checked) {
            ul.removeChild(listItem[i]);
        }
    }
  });
  
  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.type = 'checkbox';
  var label = document.createElement("label");
  var labelText = document.createElement("span");

  labelText.innerText = input.value;
  label.appendChild(checkBox);
  label.appendChild(labelText);
  listItem.appendChild(label);
  listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
  list.appendChild(listItem);
  inputItem.focus();
  inputItem.select();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>To-Do List</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>To-Do List</h1>
  <form onsubmit="return addItem('list', this.inputItem)">
    <input type="text" id="inputItem">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <ul id="list">
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: `ul` is not declared

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, there are a few little mistakes in the code:

`var list = document.getElementById(list);` - You're using the list as the parameter, not a string.

`while(listItem[i] && listItem[i].children[0].checked) {` - Not sure why you're using `while` here instead of `if`.

`ul.removeChild(listItem[i]);` - `ul` is commented a few lines above.

Besides these, the delete does not work because of the following line:
`if(listItem[i] && listItem[i].children[0].checked) {`

If you analyze the DOM, the list item contains a `<label></label>` that contains the input, which means `children[0]` is not what you expect it to be.

Therefore, **fixing the issues mentioned above** and replacing the check in the delete callback function with

```
if(listItem[i] && listItem[i].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked) {
    list.removeChild(listItem[i]);
}
```

should be your fix.